# How to change button's background in WP7 Silverlight on mouse down?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have buttons in my applications, and I've set a background for each.

When I'm pressing on the button, and before releasing it, the background turns to be just a white rectangle.

How can i set another image instead of the white rectangle?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this absolutely answers your question, but have a look at Visual States: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2008/06/10/visual-state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Blend` click `Edit Template - Edit a copy`, than go to `States` tab, select `Focused`, expand visual tree and remove animations on button background and border

Or

In `Blend` click `Edit Template - Edit a copy`, than go to `xaml` and remove anything in `Focused` visual state